# Is there an idiom or a phrase that means "he's a talented writer"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Is there an idiom or a phrase that means "he's a talented writer"? I can think of a few way of expressing it, but none of them sound particularly good or idiomatic even. Most of them sounds weird.

For example:

> He had a very masterful pen.
>
> He had a very majestic prose.

Not sure if you would agree, but those two sound awkward and weird, and not particularly eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the way he physically writes (ie handwriting, style, etc)

> He shows great *[penmanship](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penmanship)*

Answer (score 1):

Going off your first example, I would more naturally say that as:

> He was a master with a pen **OR** He was a master with the pen

Answer (score 0):

"Silver tongue" might apply here, but it is more about speaking, but could apply to writing as well.